# Google blocking ads because of Blazor .dll

Tags: blazor, google-ads-api, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor wasm and Google is blocking advertisement because "unwanted software", could it be because of .dll files? Has anybody solved it?

Comment: Blocking ads is usually a good thing. What is your _exact_ problem?

Comment: Google ads is blocking our maketing campain, because of binary .dll files.

Comment: @Rafaelguinho, did you found any solution?